# Consume REST API with only access of TSL1.2 in C#

Tags: c#, rest

We are doing integration with one third party to send and receive data. Third Party have created one REST API with SSL and deployed on their server. In server, for security reason they have disabled all the Weak protocols like TSL1.0,TSL1.1,SSL3.0 and only enabled protocol is TSL1.2.

We want to consume it in our .net application developed in .net framework 3.5.
We have tried to bypass the SSL Validation  like below

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors) { return true; };

But service is hitting. Then we have tried to do POC with .net framework 4.5 application and have added one more line

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Still I am not able to Consume the Web Service

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to call the web service? Are you getting any error?

Comment: System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

Comment: In .net 4.5 application We are getting below Error : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: @SumanZalodiya Download Wireshark  and see what is happening with TLS. Framework 4.6 uses TLS 1.2 by default. If you are getting unAuthorised, it could be credentials issue?